# Detecting if href link is clicked using PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like to know if its possible to check if a link is clicked in PHP.

I created a page for downloading games and I want users to be able to download the app, but must first be logged in.

So i want a senerio where a user clicked on the download button, then the code will check if the user is already logged in if not open a page to register, else start the download.

Comment: Use $_SESSION and/or $_COOKIE to check if the user's logged in. If he is, display link, if not, redirect.

Comment: PHP handles the server but you're talking about the client, it sounds like a job for JavaScript. You can, however, interact in between so that the JavaScript tells the PHP code what to remember.

Comment: Answer - **Yes you can**. when user clicked a button check user is logged in or not using $_SESSION and if it is logged in then redirect him to download.php page else redirect him to register page. Please paste your code what you have tried or not tried.

Comment: @Jonast92 can i see a sample code on how to achieve that

Comment: @AndrewP. I have already gotten the logged in / out all i want is to check if the download anchor tag is cliked

Comment: @user3655892 paste your code otherwise we can't help you. By seeing your question we can only guide you how to proceed

Comment: Do your users already login, and if so, how do you currently know they have logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an asynchronous request to the server to check it, (AJAX) return some data, and do the things you need to do based on the response.

Comment: he does not want to use jquery ajax. This can simply achieve by PHP

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you already have a user/login implementation, so this will only cover the principle behind this kind of procedure.

In complex frameworks this sort of process is handled for you, but in its most simplistic form, it performs the following:

```
if($user_is_logged_in) {
    // Perform action
} else {
    header('Location: /login'); // Redirect to login/registor page
}
```

Redirects are useful things for servers and the browsers.  Redirects can be temporary, and the process that occurs before the redirect can be designed to remember the intended action so that afterwards the original path can be continued which an additional redirect to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

You need a session. This is just a rough example of how it can be accomplished.
If the user is registered and logs in, start a session. Then if the user goes to the download page, it checks whether the session is set (valid user) if not, it redirects the user. If it is set, provide a download link, provide the file etc

**Note**: Firstly set session paramters in your php.ini file, such as how long the session should be kept alive for.

login.php

```
//If user logged in
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $username;
```

---

download.php

```
session_start();
//If the session has not been set, redirect the user
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: register.php");
    die;
}

//Otherwise
downloadFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a form to do this.

**Html**

```
<form action="download.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="download">Download file</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
// This is just for testing purposes of course
function is_logged_in() {
    return false;
}

// Check if the form was processed
if ( isset( $_POST['download'] ) ) {

    if ( is_logged_in() ) {

        // download file

    }
    else {

        // you could send a message directly or redirect the page
        echo 'You are not logged in. Please click <a href="#">here</a> to register or sign-in.';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I finally got the answer to the above question through the hint of 
@emilos comment: For peeps that this may help.

What I did was to create a javascript function that listen to clicks on the anchor tag, this function then calls the php page on the server. The PHP page checks if the user is logged in / not iF logged in it return 1 else 0 back to client.

The client recieved this response with the help of AJAX, then I used an if statement to know if the user should be allowed to download or not

This is how I achieved it

AJAX

```
function ajaxFunction(appName) {
          var ajaxRequest = null;
          try {
              ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }catch (e) {
              try {
                  ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }catch (e){
                   try {
                      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                   }catch (e) {
                       alert("Browser broken!");
                   }
                }
          }

          ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 ) {
                //alert("User_id: " +ajaxRequest.responseText);
                //If not logged in
                if (ajaxRequest.responseText == 0) {
                    window.location = "registration.php";
                }else {
                    window.location = "downloads/"+appName;
                }
            }
          }

          ajaxRequest.open("GET", "validate_user.php?checker=1",true);
          ajaxRequest.send(null);
      }
```

PHP

```
 if (isset($_GET['checker']) && $_GET['checker'] == 1) {
     validateLogin(); 
  }
    function validateLogin() {
       if (!isLoggedIn()) {
           //Not logged in
           echo("0");
       }else {
           echo("1");
           //Logged in
       }
   } 

   function isLoggedIn() {
       return (isset($_SESSION['user_id']));
   }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onClick="ajaxFunction('Pencil.apk');"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></a>
```